# Can't cross compile using clang

Tags: c, linux, clang, llvm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile gnu which for ARM using clang from x86_64, but I can't seem to get the correct output. After compiling and running 'make' I get resulting ELF file, but when I run 'file which' I get the following:

```
which: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

which would indicate that it wasn't compiled for the correct target, because when I cross compile using gcc, I get the following:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter 
/lib/ld-linux.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=077463715830376120e14ecd3b8ff9b80ba765cd, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

This is the command I'm using at the moment:

```
./configure CC=/home/anon/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/build/bin/clang 
-target arm-linux-gnueabi LD=/home/anon/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/build/lib/LLVMgold.so 
LDFLAGS='-fuse-ld=gold' RANLIB=/home/anon/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/build/bin/llvm-ranlib
```

I've also tried using -host which is what I used when cross compiling with gcc, but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to pass `-target arm-linux-gnueabi` as `CFLAGS` / `CXXFLAGS` variable. Or, alternatively, you can just create a symbolic link from `clang` to `arm-linux-gnueabi-clang`. Note that if your project uses C++, then you'd need to override `CXX` as well.